# How do you determine the commands a Windows App will accept?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

As an example the OneNote [Windows App](http://www.theverge.com/2015/3/26/8295177/microsoft-windows-apps-universal-apps) will accept.
**onenote-cmd://**
This will activate the app if it's open, or open it if it is closed.

It also accepts
**onenote-cmd://quicknote/?onOpen=typing**
This creates a new note.

How do I determine the other commands, if any, that OneNote (or any other Windows App)?

Comment: You ask the people who wrote the program what commands they support.

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Jerry.  Was just waiting to see if any other answers came along.
Know anyone on the OneNote team I could reach out to? :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "probe" into an app and know which commands will work.

For each application, you will have to look at the documentation.

There may also be even more additional undocumented commands. But, by the nature of being undocumented, someone would have to tell you about their existance in order to find out.